# How to Excel cell concotenet text url click to open url link in browser?

Tags: excel, vba

How to Excel cell concatenate text URL and click to open URL link in browser?

[image]

Comment: Please see my file pic and help me

Comment: Ab columns cell my link url lots of character

Comment: This question actually seems quite sensible at heart, but desperately needs cleaning up. I suspect you'll get solid answers if you edit your question to tidy up the formatting and include a better example of what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

How about if you replace your Concatenate formula with:

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCAT(A2:AA2))
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to achieve this using VBA and actually open the link in the browser then the following will help:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
    hyperlinkValue = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(ws.Range("A2:AA2").Value)), "")
    'get the concatenated values into a variable
    ws.Range("AB3").Formula = "=Hyperlink(Concat(A2:AA2)," & """Click Here To Follow Link""" & ")"
    'enter the hyperlink into the Sheet in AB3
    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=hyperlinkValue
    'follow the hyperlink
End Sub
```

Comment: This is probably just what you're looking for - you can also join and logically separate your inputs with `&`: `="https://"&A1&":"&B1&"/"&"C1`..

Comment: @MeghnathiBm updated my answer to use VBA to open the hyperlink in the browser. Hope this helps.

Comment: I want AB columns all cell link